# Get children length whilst using function as child/render props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small component that exposes some of it's methods via render props, that has some functionality based on the amount of children it has.

However, due to the children being a function, I'm needing to pass in a childTotal as a prop to the parent - which is manageable but I'd prefer if the parent could calculate this itself.

Is there a possible way to do this inside Parent or simply not worth the hassle?

```
<Parent childTotal={3}>
  {({methodOne, methodTwo, ...props) => (
    <>
      {handleFuncs(methodOne, methodTwo)}
      <Child {...props} />
      <Child {...props} />
      <Child {...props} />
    </>
  )}
</Parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this: https://codesandbox.io/s/mmk5wq1rxx

Have a look into the console down there, it seems to be doing what you need, I am not sure if this is the most elegant solution though.